# What is meaning of timezone id of Google Timezone API?

Tags: google-maps, timezone

I am developing reservation app for people worldwide. Therefore, we need time picker based on timezone and have chosen Google Timezone API for achieving it.

According Google Document, they offered timezone id for specific location.

However, i could get no informations of timezone list.
They just suggest one xml file as like below.

> timeZoneId: a string containing the ID of the time zone, such as "America/Los_Angeles" or "Australia/Sydney". These IDs are defined by Unicode Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR) project, and currently available in file timezone.xml. When a timezone has several IDs, the canonical one is returned. In timezone.xml, this is the first alias of each timezone. For example, "Asia/Calcutta" is returned, not "Asia/Kolkata".

[the link of timezone.xml](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/bcp47/timezone.xml)

People may say that there is a list you need!

Unfortunately, the list is useless.

For example, if i query for New York, i could get datas as like below.

```
{
   "dstOffset":3600,
   "rawOffset":-18000,
   "timeZoneId":"America\/New_York",
   "timeZoneName":"Eastern Daylight Time"
}
```

But, in the the xml file, there is no 'America/New_York'. There is 'America/New_York US/Eastern' instead.

That was not a unique identifier.

In conclusion, my question is what the meaning of Timezone ID is.

Are the values(timezone ID) standard as known (like ISO)?
If yes, please let me know where it is.

Comment: I also wondered about the same thing. There is IANA, Windows TimeZone format and a mention about POSIX. Would be nice to know exactly the meaning and reason behind a timezoneId.

Answer (score 3):

These are IANA time zone identifiers.  Read:

- https://www.iana.org/time-zones
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info

The XML file you referenced is part of the [Unicode CLDR project](http://cldr.unicode.org/).  It *uses* IANA TZ identifiers, just like Google Maps does, and just like so many other applications, frameworks, programming languages, and operating systems.  However, it is not authoritative.

Comment: Hi Matt, you answered one of my posts as well and I came to this post by researching on my own what the timezoneId from Google API is exatcly. There are a lot of terms, like IANA, Windows Timezone format, POSIX, CLDR. It is a bit confusing to be honest. What exactly did you mean when you wrote "it is not authorative"? If the timezone ids that several companies use, come from IANA then I would assume that is exactly authorative as IANA is an international organization.

Comment: In this particular post, I was referring to the file in the CLDR project.  That file is not the source of time zone identifiers, but rather it uses the time zone identifiers authored by the IANA TZ data.  Additionally, IANA is only "authoritative" about those identifiers, but not the time zones themselves.  Only the individual governments responsible for each time zone are authoritative in that way.  Unlike ITU and IERS which standardizes timekeeping (UTC, leap seconds, etc.), there is no international body that standardizes time zones.